# Django POST request Via ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to submit values via ajax to django backend,but I'm keep getting this error `Advice matching query does not exist` , But it does exist in the database. I dont know what I am doing wrong.
Here is my code snippet for AJAX Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "recsystem:saveData" %}',
    data: {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : "{{  csrf_token  }}",
        'ansId' : data.ansId,
        'queTitle': data.queTitle,
        'queText' : data.queText,
        'desc': data.desc,
        'optionType': data.optionType,
        'anstextArray': data.anstextArray,
        'ansAdvicesArray': data.ansAdvicesArray
     },
     success: function(data){
         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(error){
         console.log(error);
     }
});
```

Here is my function in Django view to save this data.

```
def saveData(request):

if request.method =='POST' and request.is_ajax():    
    q = Question()
    q.question_title = request.POST['queTitle']
    q.question_text = request.POST['queText']
    q.description = request.POST['desc']
    q.options_type = request.POST['optionType']
    q.save()

    if not request.POST['ansId'] is None:
        followup = FollowUp()
        followup.description = ""
        followup.answer = Answer.objects.get(pk=request.POST['ansId'])
        followup.question = q
        followup.save()

    if not request.POST.get('anstextArray', False) is None:
        answers = []
        advices = []
        answers = request.POST.get('anstextArray', False)
        advices = request.POST.get('ansAdvicesArray', False)
        for an, ad in zip(itertools.repeat(answers), itertools.repeat(advices)):
            adviceList = []
            adviceList = ad
            answer = Answer()
            answer.question = q
            answer.answer_text = an

            for id in itertools.repeat(adviceList):
                answer.advice = Advice.objects.get(pk=id)

            answer.save()

    return JsonResponse({'result':'ok'})

else:
    return JsonResponse({'result':'nok'})
```

Here is my Database model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
  question_text = models.TextField(max_length = 3000)
  description = models.TextField(max_length = 3000)
  options_type = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

  def __str__(self):
         return self.question_title

class Advice(models.Model):
  advice_label = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
  advice_text = models.TextField(max_length = 3000)
  time_stamp = models.TextField( default=timezone.now, max_length= 2000)


  def __str__(self):
        return self.advice_label


class Answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  answer_text = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
  advices = models.ManyToManyField(Advice)
  def __str__(self):
         return self.answer_text


class FollowUp(models.Model):
  description = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
  answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The problem lies somewhere, where I am trying to save the arrays as lists as then iterating through it.

```
Traceback: 

File "C:\Users\habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "C:\Users\habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\habib\Desktop\recommender\src\recsystem\views.py" in saveData
177.                     answer.advice = Advice.objects.get(pk=id)

File "C:\Users\habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
 85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, 
**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
380.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /recsystem/saveData/
Exception Value: Advice matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Could you please post your traceback (errors)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question bit unclear to me but this kind of error literally happened when you trying to retrieve a nonexistent data from db using `Model.objects.get()` method.

I suspect your problem lies on following code.

```
Advice.objects.get(pk=id)
```

So to ensure that, debug this point to get the `id` and then manually checked in db whether the data associated with that `id` is exist or not.

Also you can use other method to retrieve data from db like `get_object_or_404(Advice, pk=id)` or even `filter()` method can help you.

Comment: Well thats pretty clear that the error is in that line, but the question is why?
Since the id exists in the database base and so does the object

Comment: @SyedFarhanHabib have you solved it yet? BTW Are you certain that id is valid for every case in that loop. I really don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Type: DoesNotExist means that you filter based on the pk, but the data behind "=" is not an ID. 
Make sure this itertools.repeat(adviceList) is a list of ID.